# HTML Form checkboxes not submitting as I expect

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, checkbox

[Solution: Change my names to arrays by concatenating "[]" to the end. Also, change my IDs to be unique values to conform to HTML specifications]

I'm creating a form, that has a matrix (html table) of checkboxes with one user per row, and user permissions on the columns. Each cell has a checkbox. Each checkbox in a row has the "name" set to the user's email address (unique). The values of the checkboxes are the IDs of the particular permission. when I click the submit button, and inspect the params I get back from the HTTP POST, only the right-most checkbox is set for rows that have multiple boxes checked.

For example, there are three checkboxes, first and second checked, third unchecked. I only get back the name=id of that second checkbox.

I'm building the form in Rails, although I don't believe that to be relevant really. Also, the browser that's giving this behavior is Chrome, Iceweasel, and Epiphany... So I think it's my form.

An excerpt of my form:

```
<tr>
                <td>UserOne</td>
                <td>one@oreo.com</td>
                <td>
                        <input checked="checked" id="one_oreo.com" name="one@oreo.com" type="checkbox" value="1" />
                </td>
                <td>
                        <input id="one_oreo.com" name="one@oreo.com" type="checkbox" value="2" />
                </td>
                <td>
                        <input id="one_oreo.com" name="one@oreo.com" type="checkbox" value="3" />
                </td>
                <td>
                        <input checked="checked" id="one_oreo.com" name="one@oreo.com" type="checkbox" value="4" />
                </td>
                <td>
                        <input id="one_oreo.com" name="one@oreo.com" type="checkbox" value="5" />
                </td>
                <td>
                        <input id="one_oreo.com" name="one@oreo.com" type="checkbox" value="6" />
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: By the way - Oreo.com isn't real - it's a codename :)

Comment: More than one item with the same id is invalid html anyway.

Comment: You should be using unique id's - an id value should never be repeated.  Are you using a JS validator on the form?  It could be contributing to/causing your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have set the name="" on all of them to the same thing, so it is going to replace whatever value was originally there when you tick more than one checkbox.

Either give each checkbox a different name e.g. `name="one@oreo.com_check_1"` or turn them in to an array using `name="one@oreo.com[]"` This will then store all values passed to it in an array that you can then process after the form has been submitted!

Comment: [] is the solution! I will accept this answer in 4 minutes. Thanks :)

Comment: I have a serious concern about this. In html, you are SUPPOSED to have the name identical for all the checkboxes you want grouped together. And it is SUPPOSED to send the ones that are checked by default. So this is going against the html standard, by requiring that you use [] array syntax.

Comment: @Donato Just because one specification tells you that you are SUPPOSED to do something one way does not mean that the server side languages you are using are going to play nicely. I haven't really read the HTML specification on checkboxes in much detail to know if you're correct or not but after a quick search this seems to be the most common way around this issue. We can't always have every language working together flawlessly, following each others specifications exactly, so sometimes you have to make exceptions to work around an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The names of your checkboxes need to be unique.  I suggest puttitempeh user id and permission id in the name.  Also you should change the Ida accordingly.  The ids don't affect form submission but it is incorrect to have multiple elements with the same id in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can't name the name param to the same value for each row.   Checkboxes need to be unique or at least an array.   Radio buttons are where you would use the same name value.

Comment: You can name checkboxes with the same name, i have done it plenty. The id property is the only one that needs to be unique.